# Unknown CMake command "ign_find_package"

Tags: gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to compile a plugin for ign-gazebo.

Procedure I followed:

1. I copied my plugin folder "mimic_joint_plugin" to **ign-gazebo/examples/plugin**.
2. made a build dir
3. compiled the directory using `cmake ..` command and got this error on the console.

**Version**: Ignition citadel

```
adwaitnaik@ubuntu:~/ign_ws/src/ign-gazebo/examples/plugin/mimic_joint_plugin$ mkdir build
adwaitnaik@ubuntu:~/ign_ws/src/ign-gazebo/examples/plugin/mimic_joint_plugin$ cd build
adwaitnaik@ubuntu:~/ign_ws/src/ign-gazebo/examples/plugin/mimic_joint_plugin/build$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/adwaitnaik/ign_ws/src/ign-gazebo/examples/plugin/mimic_joint_plugin/build/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/melodic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/melodic
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found suitable version "2.7.17", minimum required is "2") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python2
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/adwaitnaik/ign_ws/src/ign-gazebo/examples/plugin/mimic_joint_plugin/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found version "2.7.17") 
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.29
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:208 (ign_find_package):
  Unknown CMake command "ign_find_package".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/adwaitnaik/ign_ws/src/ign-gazebo/examples/plugin/mimic_joint_plugin/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/adwaitnaik/ign_ws/src/ign-gazebo/examples/plugin/mimic_joint_plugin/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

***Note: ign_ws is the workspace in which I have installed all the ignition libraries from the source and compiled them.***

Please can anybody suggest a solution on how to comile plugins for ign-gazebo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26770/unknown-cmake-command-%22ign_find_package%22./) by [Adwait](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/42410/adwait/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 7 on 2021-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Have you sourced the Ignition workspace overlay containing [ign-cmake](https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ign-cmake) before trying to build `mimic_joint_plugin` plugin?

For example, try `. ~/ign_ws/install/setup.bash` if you used `colcon` to build the Ignition libraries.

---

Originally posted by [AndrejOrsula](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/44778/andrejorsula/) with karma: 101 on 2021-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adwait](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/42410/adwait/) on 2021-04-04**:
I had sourced the workspace once during the installation process (in the end). Yes, I have used colon to build the libraries. This is a system plugin. My question is how do you compile a plugin when you have a .cc, .hh, and CMakeLists.txt files ready?

**Comment by [AndrejOrsula](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/44778/andrejorsula/) on 2021-04-05**:
You need to source the workspace also in the particular terminal that you are using to build the plugin, not just once in another shell instance. Alternatively, put source command in your `~/.bashrc` so that it is done automatically for each new terminal.

I am saying this because CMake Error `Unknown CMake command "ign_find_package"` indicates that `ign-cmake` is not sourced in your current shell.

**Comment by [Adwait](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/42410/adwait/) on 2021-04-06**:
@AndrejOrsula thanks, that worked for me.

**Comment by [florian.pix](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/81881/florian.pix/) on 2022-05-22**:
how can I source that workspace when I installed ignition gazebo from [binaries](https://gazebosim.org/docs/edifice/install_ubuntu) ?